# How can I connect Redmi K20 Pro back to my PC?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, android, mtp

It was all fine before I removed windows 10 old folder from my system due to space problems from my c drive, I can connect easly my redmi phone through USB and it will show in explorer like a charm.  But now I cant connect my redmi phone through USB. Its not showing as drives as earlier. I can see it in device manger with driver error (yellow exclamation). I have been trying to get the driver back by searching google for the last two days and I failed and ended up in a mess. my phone are redmi Note 4, Redmi 4A, Redmi Note 7 Pro and Redmi K20 Pro. Can anyone help me with the correct driver to get  back my phones connected to PC. My PC is Lenova G50 with windows 10 Build 19041.vb_release.191206-1406. 64 bit os.

I am getting this while I try installing a pack which I recieved from web

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted from Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238760/44325

Comment: that isn't cross-post. question moved to superuser because of my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

first thing you should do is pick the yellow exclamation, check which `.inf` file is assigned and delete this file from windows/inf directory

pick the yellow exclamation und uninstall drivers

disable windows driver signature enforcement and reboot

double check phone settings, maybe switch to PTP and then back to MTP mode, let windows reinstall drivers itself

if MTP drivers doesn't install automatically,`wpdmtp.inf` is missing. install Windows [Media Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack)

Comment: By following the instruction I managed to install above shown image to all green. But still my phone is not showing up in explorer. Its showing in system tray but cant explore. Thank you for the support

Comment: Still MTP Driver missing :(( where can I find one to install ? @alecxs

Comment: did you switch to PTP and wait for drivers installed, then switch back to MTP as suggested?

Comment: Today I  tried when switching to PTP its getting detecting and able to see the device with two folders.  while switching back to File transfer its failing when I check the device manager there was an error in MTP driver saying - A service installation section in this INF is invalid - I uninstalled then tried installing automaticaly again the driver failed. I installed the media pack through setting/app/optional features. Thank  you @alecxs at least its get detecting in PTP mode. Thank you for the help you are providing

Comment: unfortunately can't really help with windows 10 as i am not facing any problems with windows 7. anyway adb pull is the recommended method for file transfer as MTP is weak protocol